# Facebook not detecting og:title, og:description, or og:image

Tags: facebook, vue.js, facebook-opengraph, nuxt.js

I've built a Vue app using Nuxt.js and for some reason `og:` tags are not working on facebook. I see them in the source code, and run the site through the FB debugger, but it says I have no required `og:` meta tags.

Site here:
https://staymacro-staging.netlify.com/editorial/caleb/

Code in the page:

```
  head () {
    return {
      title: `${this.title}`,
      meta: [{
        hid: `description`,
        name: 'description',
        content: `${this.description}`
      },
      {
        hid: `og-title`,
        property: 'og:title',
        content: `${this.title}`
      },
      {
        hid: `og-description`,
        property: 'og:description',
        content: `${this.description}`
      },
      {
        hid: `og-image`,
        property: 'og:image',
        content: `${this.image}`
      },
      {
        hid: `og-url`,
        property: 'og:url',
        content: `https://staymacro.com/${this.$route.path}`
      }]
    }
  },
```

Sharing works on Slack, iMessage, Twitter, etc. but just not on Facebook

Answer (score 0):

The og:url in the source does not match the url you presented: https://staymacro.com//editorial/caleb

That is the relevant URL where the tags are taken, and it does not work (no SSL, page not found).

You can even see this in the debugger: "Curl-Fehler: 51 (SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE)". Check out the "canonical URL".

Comment: Thank you!! I also noticed that relevant og: data wasnt being updated in Safari. Could this be a similar reason?

Comment: well...there is a ssl error, and the http page cannot be found, so yes, definitely